# Writing to File With A record

Tags: file, delphi, records

I've been working on assignment where I have to simulate an actual booking system.

The user can create an event which actually just names a text file that they can write to later on.

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: textfile;
  usersFilename: string;
begin
  usersFilename := Inputbox('Enter the name of the Event', '', '');  
  AssignFile(f, usersFilename);
  ReWrite(f, usersFilename);
  WriteLn(f, usersFilename);
  CloseFile(f);
  Reset(f);
end;
```

So now I've created a file with the name of the event which they should be able to write to with this

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Customer: TCustomer;
    f: textfile;
    usersFilename: string;
begin
    usersFilename := Inputbox('Event Name', '', '');
    AssignFile(f, usersFilename);

    with Customer do
    begin
        FirstName := 'John';
        LastName := 'Smith';
        EventDate := 'Grimworth';
        SeatNumber := '1';
        PhoneNumber := '1';
        Adress := '7 Park Drive';
    end;
end;
```

Originally I just had inputboxes that would write to the file after the user wrote the name of the event, however after re reading the assignment outline I realised I HAVE to use records, so now I'm trying to use them but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. No error actually pops up its just if you open the text file there is nothing in it, empty.

Comment: Buttone2Click is not writing to the file. You also need to open the file and write to it in that method.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at your second block. There are a couple of problems:

1. You file is the wrong type. It should be a `File of TCustomer` instead of a `TextFile`. Record files are files of the particular type.
2. You are never writing any thing to the file. To write something to the file you need to use something like `Write(f, ....)`
3. You don't actually open the file. You need to use `Reset(f)` to open the file for reading and writing or `ReWrite(f)` to create the file (will also blank it if one already exists).
4. You should close the file when you are finished with it.

To put it all together, your block of code should look something like this:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Customer: TCustomer;
  f: File of TCustomer;
  usersFilename: string;
begin
  usersFilename := Inputbox('Event Name', '', '');
  AssignFile(f, usersFilename);
  // Open if it exists or create the file
  if FileExists(usersFilename) then
    Reset(f)
  else
    ReWrite(f);

  // Set up our data for writing. This information could
  // be retrieved from text boxes, etc.
  with Customer do
  begin
    FirstName := 'John';
    LastName := 'Smith';
    EventDate := 'Grimworth';
    SeatNumber := '1';
    PhoneNumber := '1';
    Adress := '7 Park Drive';
  end;

  // Write the data to the file
  Write(f, Customer);
  CloseFile(f);
end;
```

One thing this is not taking into account is any existing data. It will start writing from the beginning of the file so you should investigate `Seek` for that.

Comment: WOW oh man thank you dude I was really struggling with this seriously thank you

Comment: Just a note, `TCustomer` string fields must be declared as ShortStrings. This is an outdated technique for storing data in a text file.

Comment: And in case someone wonders what to use instead, search for CSV,XML and JSON storage.

Comment: As LU RD wrote you need to use ShortStrings or fixed lenght strings like FirstName: String[15];
This is needed in order to maintain fixed size of record you are writing into file so that you can use seek method to move to specific recod in your file.

As for this aproach being outdated, I don't think so. The main advantage of this aproach is that you can write or read almost any Delphi type in binary form using it. The only data type that can't be written using this approach are Pointers since their value will be different when you start your application next time.

Comment: @SilverWarior, by outdated I mean that in a Unicode world it is difficult to store normal Unicode strings in a ShortString format. The use of [ShortString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ShortString) is deprecated since at least a decade, and not available for the mobile compilers. As for the conveniance to mix data types in a record container for storage, I agreee. We still are using TP7 code in production using this technique, although at least 90% of the use cases was converted to ini-files 20 years ago.